# Capture keywords used and results clicked by user in SP 2013 search web part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-server, search, search-results

We are using a Search query and a search results web part, we want to capture the keyword used and search result clicked by the user. We want to capture this information to improve search query suggestions. We have used a override to the autocomplete feature of ajaxtoolkit for suggesting queries as the user types in keywords. Now how to we capture this?